# Unable to clone keyspace using DSE Backup & Restore Service

Tags: restore, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I'm trying to restore from old keyspace to new keyspace but getting below error.

```
cqlsh> RESTORE geo1
   ... FROM BACKUP ks1_config_name-20220916194400.146-ea3173fc-760e-4dcd-9d7b-6f928c40eab5
   ... FROM STORE ks1_store
   ... INTO KEYSPACE ks_2;
SyntaxException: line 4:5 no viable alternative at input 'KEYSPACE' (...ks1_config_name-20220916194400.146-ea3173fc-760e-4dcd-9d7b-6f928c40eab5FROM STORE ks1_storeINTO [KEYSPACE]...)

=====================================
cqlsh> list backups from keyspace ks_1;

 id                                                                      | backup_time                     | store     | keyspace | tables   | nodes                                  | schema_versions | status      | details                                              | per_dc_status | per_dc_details
-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------------------------------------+-----------------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+---------------+----------------
 ks1_config_name-20220916194400.146-ea3173fc-760e-4dcd-9d7b-6f928c40eab5 | 2022-09-16 19:44:00.146000+0000 | ks1_store |     ks_1 | {'geo1'} | {ea3173fc-760e-4dcd-9d7b-6f928c40eab5} |    IN AGREEMENT | FULL_BACKUP | All the token ring nodes were successfully backed up |              {} |               {}

(1 rows)

===========================
```

Comment: Does ks_2 exist?

Comment: yes.

cqlsh> desc KEYSPACES

mv1                    movie          ks_1            system_distributed
system_virtual_schema  system_schema  system          system_traces
dse_system_local       system_auth    dse_leases      dse_perf
dse_security           system_views   system_backups  dse_insights_local
solr_admin             ks_2           dse_insights    dse_system

cqlsh>

Comment: Hi Aaron,
Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The `SyntaxException` is coming from the `KEYSPACE` in the `... INTO KEYSPACE ...` section of the [DSE Backup & Restore Service](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsBackupRestoreServiceAbout.html) command.

The correct syntax for cloning a keyspace to another is:

```
RESTORE source_keyspace
  FROM BACKUP backup_config
  FROM STORE backup_store
  INTO destination_keyspace;
```

For example, in my cluster where I have this backup:

```
cqlsh> LIST BACKUPS FROM KEYSPACE originalks ;

 id         | backup_time                     | store        | keyspace   | tables    | ...
------------+---------------------------------+--------------+------------+-----------+-----
 bkpconf-ID | 2022-09-21 10:53:21.098000+0000 | backup_store | originalks | {'users'} | ...
```

This is the command I ran to restore the `originalks` keyspace to the `cloneks` keyspace:

```
cqlsh> RESTORE originalks FROM BACKUP bkpconf-ID FROM STORE backup_store INTO cloneks;
```

I'm sorry that the example syntax in the docs is incorrect so I will get it fixed. Cheers!

Comment: I have followed above syntax, keyspace is restored but table data is not restored.

cqlsh> RESTORE ks_1 FROM BACKUP test_config-20220921082552.181-ea3173fc-760e-4dcd-9d7b-6f928c40eab5 FROM STORE test_store INTO ks_2;
 restore_id
--------------------------------------
 ba16fae0-39b7-11ed-bc45-61e5a5e11b22

cqlsh> select * from ks_2.geo1;

 id | city | country | countrycode | population | state
----+------+---------+-------------+------------+-------

(0 rows)

Comment: You can clone a specific table with `RESTORE ks.table_name ...` but I didn't have to do that in my case. When I cloned a keyspace, all the tables in it were cloned too. Cheers!